# How should I design an enum with inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, enums, functional-programming

I'm trying to enumerate functions that parse data (ID3 tags). At the moment, I've got an enum that looks like this:

```
enum Id3V1Layout {
  HEADER(range(fromString(), 0, 3)),
  TITLE(range(fromString(), 3, 33)),
  ARTIST(range(fromString(), 33, 63)),
  ALBUM(range(fromString(), 63, 93)),
  YEAR(range(fromString(), 93, 97)),
  /** length is 30 if zero bit != 0, else 28 */
  COMMENT(b -> range(fromString(), 97, b[125] == 0 ? 125 : 127).parse(b)),
  TRACK(b -> b[125] == 0 ? range(v -> (int) v[0], 126, 127).parse(b) : -1),
  GENRE(b -> b[127] < 0 ? null : Genre.values()[b[127]]);

  public final Id3FieldParser parser;

  static Id3FieldParser range(Id3FieldParser fn, int from, int to) {
    return b -> fn.parse(Arrays.copyOfRange(b, from, to));
  }

  static Id3FieldParser fromString() {
    return bytes -> new String(bytes).trim();
  }

  Id3V1Layout(Id3FieldParser parser) {
    this.parser = parser;
  }
}
```

(Short explanation: Each element defines how to parse the specific field. `range` is a method that returns an `Id3FieldParser` functional interface object.)

Now my question is: Since I want to implement the ID3v2 layout later, how can I make `Id3V1Layout` have the same constructor and methods as `Id3V2Layout`?

**I want to be able to use the `Id3Layout` class** instead of hardcoding `Id3V1Layout` or `Id3V2Layout`.

But enums cannot inherit from abstract classes, and I can't define an constructor or attributes in an interface.

So how can I define different elements with different parameters while using one common class that has the attribute(s) both enums have?

Comment: I am not sure if I completely understand what you want, but the word "using" in "... using one common class ..." may be a hint that you actually want composition instead of inheritance - meaning that you could use instances of a common class which contains the common attributes and methods in the different enums. Polymorphism if needed can then be achieved by exposing methods via an interface implemented by the enums.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for something like this?

```
class Id3Layout {
    public interface ParseLayout {
        Id3FieldParser getParser();
    }
    private static Id3FieldParser range(Id3FieldParser fn, int from, int to) {
        return b -> fn.parse(Arrays.copyOfRange(b, from, to));
    }
    private static Id3FieldParser fromString() {
        return bytes -> new String(bytes).trim();
    }
    public enum Id3LayoutVersions {
        V1(Id3V1Layout.values()),
        V2(Id3V2Layout.values());

        private ParseLayout[] parseLayout;
        private Id3LayoutVersions(ParseLayout[] pl) {
            parseLayout = pl;
        }
        public ParseLayout[] getParseLayoutTokens() { return parseLayout; }
    }
    public enum Id3V1Layout implements ParseLayout {
        HEADER(range(fromString(), 0, 3)),
        ...;
        private Id3FieldParser parser;
        private Id3V1Layout(Id3FieldParser parser) {
            this.parser = parser;
        }
        public Id3FieldParser  getParser() { return parser; }
    }
    public enum Id3V2Layout implements ParseLayout {
        HEADER(range(fromString(), 0, 3)),
        ...;
        private Id3FieldParser parser;
        private Id3V2Layout(Id3FieldParser parser) {
            this.parser = parser;
        }
        public Id3FieldParser  getParser() { return parser; }
    }
```

Comment: `range()` and `fromString()` need to be static since you can't make a static reference to a non static method.